# Fix data parameter type match with key object parameter type

Tags: typescript

I don't know how to fix the type parameter of this function.

This is my interface.
Each property has its own value.

```js
interface TypeValidation {
  nin: true | "used" | "wrong" | "check" | false
  title: true | "plsSelect" | false
  firstName: true | "plsInsert" | false
  lastName: true | "plsInsert" | false
}
```

I use this; it works but I can pass anything to the function.

```js
const reducers = {
  validationChange: ( state, action: PayloadAction<{
    type: keyof TypeValidation
    data: TypeValidation[keyof TypeValidation]
  }> ) => {
  // type error
  // state[action.payload.type] = action.payload.data
    state = {
      ...state,
      [action.payload.type]: action.payload.data
    }
  }
}
```

Types not working since I can still pass anything like "used" | "wrong" | "check" | "plsInsert".

How do I fix it?

```js
dispatch(
 validationChange({
  type: "title",
  data: "plsSelect" // << Here It should true | "plsSelect" | false
 })
)
```

Comment: For cleanness, use `boolean` instead of `true | false`

Answer (score 1):

When one type depedends on another type, you need [generics.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) In this case, the type of `data` depends on the type of `type`, so so you need generics.

```
const reducers = {
  validationChange: <T extends keyof TypeValidation>(
    state,
    action: PayloadAction<{
      type: T
      data: TypeValidation[T]
    }>
  ) => {
    return { // changed to return
      ...state,
      [action.payload.type]: action.payload.data
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's a working example, without redux.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEBqcA2wAJnGMAPYjIDeAUMsiKAFzJhQCuKAPsgEQcAzhCJ9kvPgHcolAOZiJCABYQEAawXJ4+YfTbAw+CK3Zdx-TDoDKEIwjCbtuhjGBRBYAHJwAtsbacPBY6AJIgwlAO5k4QevhwHt5+JoHmfJaCYRFRvDG0AL60tKCQsIgoVmCkKBAAHpAgRIJoWLgExKQUVNSFtAiUHshQIhxI7sgAvDR6AG7tJGSUAMJKcCCyEAA8qMh1DU3IahDo5DAt2HiEC10AfAAUHtWsldUANMiIiyCsdAwMYK1WKg9AwFnAga1Lh0vgBtVAAXT0+QAlM8qpBpn8hhAwBwoN0QX8AHQkx6QV6Ehgwz5dIkA7Dw1g0yhEsGEwoMQq9IiqeLDZD9cJgZA+dAvSBo6pFYZEUbQQREuZXTrLVbrCB3UXiiDvX5sQH8MiGCB8Cmg0jg4KCGx2Bx6AD09oAegB+ArIoA)